# What data isn't included in the Public Data Release of the 2019 Developer Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

If I remember correctly, when I took the survey, there was a question about which famous or influential people I follow in tech. Am I remembering wrong? I don't see this data in the [data dump](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/21/public-data-release-of-stack-overflows-2019-developer-survey/?cb=1).

Which data gathered on the survey was not included in the public release of data?

Comment: I think every question that had an plain text entry field is excluded. To prevent mishaps in case people did leave PII there.