# Can the "Other" language, platform, etc. data be included in the 2019 Developer Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2019

Currently, the data shows nothing after "Other(s)" in fields such as `LanguageWorkedWith`, `LanguageDesireNextYear`, `PlatformWorkedWith`.

An example for `LanguageWorkedWith` in row 10:

```
Bash/Shell/PowerShell;C#;HTML/CSS;JavaScript;Python;Ruby;Rust;SQL;TypeScript;WebAssembly;Other(s):
```

Comment: [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) commented in a [related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385369/what-data-isnt-included-in-the-public-data-release-of-the-2019-developer-survey), "I think every question that had an plain text entry field is excluded. To prevent mishaps in case people did leave PII there."

Comment: @JiriTousek Good reference! Although that question gave the example of the "influential people" which is liable to have names. However, it would be pretty interesting/valuable to see trends in technology of things "below the fold" per se. Even if the top 100-[x]00 topics were "whitelisted" in the  available data.

Comment: @JiriTousek what is PLL? (PII? P2?)

Comment: @jrh "Personally identifying information" (this TLA even comes as first hit on Google for me, which is admittedly rare).